# How to set maximal debugging/log level output from PHP command line?

Tags: php, command-line

I am starting a PHP daemon from command line in env A successfully. Yet, in env B, it stops right after being started. Same code. No error message.

I was wondering how I could set the maximum debug/log level output when launching the daemon. Is there a specific parameter I can pass? I am willing to collect more information than nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable reporting of all messages like this:

```
$ php -d error_log= -d log_errors=1 -d error_reporting=E_ALL e.php
HAI
```

#### file e.php contents

```
<?php

error_log('HAI');
```

You should also inspect the exit code of the daemon as that may be a standard [unix exit code](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html) that would give you some clue.

```
php e.php ; echo $?
```

#### Refs

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: Keep in mind that any of those settings may be overridden at runtime witn error_reporting() or ini_set()